# ruby - Can I create a md5 hash of length 8?

Tags: ruby, md5

Is it possible to create a md5 hash of 8 characters long?

Comment: FYI: Hashing 2000 strings using 8 hexits, the probability of a hash collision is 0.047% ( ~ 1 / 2,000 ).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) creates 16-byte hashes. You can of course crop the string to eight characters, as with `myString[0..7]`, but note that this not a valid MD5 hash any more.

Answer (score 8):

```
require 'digest'

Digest::MD5.hexdigest("My secret")[0...8]
```

Comment: You'd end up with some collisions, right? It kind of negates the use of MD5.

Comment: That depends how many strings you are hashing. I'm just building an application which needs to hash strings to generate filenames, but there will never be more than a couple thousand different strings. In such a case, an 8-character hash would be highly unlikely to end up with collisions.

Answer (score 2):

I think md5 has a generic length depending of what it's encrypting, so you can't pre define the length of the md5 hash.

Answer (score 0):

length 8 string is not valid md5 hash.